# Tutti i "santi" giorni!

Tags: word-usage, etymology

*"Tutti i santi giorni"*, o *"tutto il santo giorno"* sono espressioni molto comuni usate per esprimere, generalmente con una connotazione negativa, un concetto di continuità e stanchezza riferendosi ad un dovere o spesso ad un lavoro.

- tutti i santi giorni mi devo alzare per andare a lavorare.
- ho studiato tutto il santo giorno.

Secondo [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tutti%20i%20santi%20giorni%2C%20tutto%20il%20santo%20giorno&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctutti%20i%20santi%20giorni%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctutto%20il%20santo%20giorno%3B%2Cc0) questo modo di dire cominciò ad essere usato nella seconda metà del 19esimo secolo.

L'espressione risulta presente nell'edizione del ***[1872](https://books.google.it/books?id=t6Q-AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA543&dq=%22tutti%20i%20santi%20giorni%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAGoVChMI0vDhzqiIyQIVhqMOCh3fkgsg#v=onepage&q=%22tutti%20i%20santi%20giorni%22&f=false)***  del *Dizionario della lingua italiana* di Niccolò Tommaseo e Bernardo Bellini:

> - Agg. [T.] Tutti i santi giorni, *come dire Tutti i giorni che fa Iddio; Sempre.* — Tutto il santo giorno, *Quant'egli è lungo; sottint. Lavorando, Aspettando, Dolendosi.* — Tutta la santa giornata, *segnatam. d'opera o di dolore.* [G.M.] Tutta la santa notte.

Qual è l'origine dell'uso di questa espressione? Perché ha assunto una connotazione negativa nonostante l'uso del termine 'santo'?

Answer (score 8):

> Perché ha assunto una connotazione negativa nonostante l'uso del termine 'santo'?

Perché è un [eufemismo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/eufemismo/), ovvero si usa un termine al posto di un altro per "ammorbidire" l'impatto dell'espressione.

È un eufemismo piuttosto "estremo" (tant'è che il valore letterale dell'espressione invece di semplicemente sfumare verso un un'accezione più morbida assume proprio la connotazione opposta di ciò che in realtà si vuole esprimere).

Quindi direi che è l'opposto; non è che l'espressione "ha assunto una connotazione negativa", ma piuttosto che un'altra espressione (per esempio "Tutti i maledetti giorni mi devo alzare per andare a lavorare." o "Ho studiato tutto il maledetto giorno.") "ha assunto un valore letterale positivo".

Comment: Sono d'accordo, un eufemismo 'estremo'. Ma la mia sensazione è che  non  sia sempre stato così e che la frase, specialmente in origine, (vedi il riferimento al Dizionario Tommeseo-Bellini) non avesse la connotazione negativa che ha oggi.

Comment: @Josh61 Non capisco se lo deduci dal dizionario o da altro, comunque può darsi, questa è giusto la mia impressione. Se trovo un filo logico consistente per un idioma, *in mancanza d'altro* ritengo sia probabile che non abbia un'etimologia "particolare" (che so, magari derivante da un aneddoto o da altro), ma che derivi semplicemente dalla sua adozione stessa come idioma e dall'uso consistente nel tempo. Quindi si, può darsi benissimo che abbia un origine più specifica, comunque personalmente per ora non ho trovato nulla.

Comment: Santificare le feste, santificare ogni giorno della nostra vita, le preghiere e la messa quotidiana sono tradizioni, ormai perse, ma molto presenti nel nostro passato e nella tradizione cattolica. La mia impressione è che nasca da lì...ma forse è solo una mia impressione. Da cui probabilmente anche, come reazione, l'uso eufemistico.

Comment: @Josh61 Non so, io l'ho sempre interpretata così, perché appunto come tu stesso hai sottolineato nella domanda l'uso eufemistico è evidente, ma può darsi benissimo che per evidenziare la contrapposizione in quello che poi è diventato l'uso idiomatico dell'espressione sia stato usato un idioma già precedentemente esistente. Lo trovo anzi piuttosto probabile. Il problema in questi casi ovviamente è sempre la mancanza di fonti. Purtroppo temo sarà impossibile comprovare la veridicità dell'una o dell'altra.